# How to know which app is playing a sound?

Tags: macos, audio

There are a couple of sounds that my mac makes, which annoy the heck out of me.

However, I don't know which application that's running is making these (perhaps it's the system itself)

Is there a way to identify which app recently caused a sound to play?

Comment: You should be able to see which apps are open on the dock or in the bar at the top.

By making note of which apps are open and which noise you hear you should be able to narrow it down. Once you have heard a sound you could go into the prefrences of all the open apps and check the sounds or notifications in their.

Which apps are open when you hear the sounds? Can you describe the sounds?

Comment: If you record and post the sounds, users may recognize them and identify the app that generates them.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest WireTap products from Ambrosia

They had the ability to differentiate sounds from different applications, however due to the nature of Lion these products no longer do that and Apples sand boxing requirement is going to make it worse.